# Loop Through Array of Labels Using Temp Variable

Tags: vb.net

I've got a 2D array of 100 labels in a 10x10 matrix (it's 2D because it represents some hardware out in the real world, if anyone cares). I want to loop through and check a conditional, and change the label background color if the conditional is false.

I've tried this ten different ways, but I keep getting an exception thrown because the temp variable I have created won't take an assignment to one of the label names.

```
'Table for correct switch module for corresponding actuator
Dim ActLabelLookup(,) As Label =
{{MTA91, MTA92, MTA93, MTA94, MTA95, MTA96, MTA97, MTA98, MTA99, MTA100},
{MTA81, MTA82, MTA83, MTA84, MTA85, MTA86, MTA87, MTA88, MTA89, MTA90},
{MTA71, MTA72, MTA73, MTA74, MTA75, MTA76, MTA77, MTA78, MTA79, MTA80},
{MTA61, MTA62, MTA63, MTA64, MTA65, MTA66, MTA67, MTA68, MTA69, MTA70},
{MTA51, MTA52, MTA53, MTA54, MTA55, MTA56, MTA57, MTA58, MTA59, MTA60},
{MTA41, MTA42, MTA43, MTA44, MTA45, MTA46, MTA47, MTA48, MTA49, MTA50},
{MTA31, MTA32, MTA33, MTA34, MTA35, MTA36, MTA37, MTA38, MTA39, MTA40},
{MTA21, MTA22, MTA23, MTA24, MTA25, MTA26, MTA27, MTA28, MTA29, MTA30},
{MTA11, MTA12, MTA13, MTA14, MTA15, MTA16, MTA17, MTA18, MTA19, MTA20},
{MTA1, MTA2, MTA3, MTA4, MTA5, MTA6, MTA7, MTA8, MTA9, MTA10}}

Private Sub UpdateActuatorStatus()
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim CurrAct As New Label

For X = 0 To (ActControl.MAX_X - 1)
    For Y = 0 To (ActControl.MAX_Y - 1)
        If TempFunctionalActuatorMatrix(X, Y) = False Then
            CurrAct = ActLabelLookup(X, Y)
            CurrAct.BackColor = Color.Firebrick
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

With this code, CurrAct is never getting set to anything. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Screen Cap]

Comment: Check the value of `ActControl.MAX_X - 1` and `ActControl.MAX_Y - 1` to ensure that it does not exceed `ActLabelLookup.GetUpperBound(0)` and  `ActLabelLookup.GetUpperBound(1)`, respectively.  What is the actual error message.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: .Net are zero-based index, that is a 9x9 matrix. **Dim ActLabelLookup(,) As New Label(9, 9) {...}**

Comment: The exception is thrown the first time my conditional resolves to False (in this case, when X=0 and Y=1). So I don't believe my issue is with exceeding upper bounds. The actual error is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in FW Qualification Suite.exe". It specifically flags the CurrAct.BackColor = Colr.Firebrick line, which is assume is because CurrAct = Nothing when I view it in the Watch window of VS15.

Comment: Does this code run after the form with MTA1, MTA2, ... MTA100 is loaded so that the label are initialized?

Comment: I suspect that ActLabelLookup(X, Y) is also null.

Comment: @JerryM: you are correct, ActLabelLookup is also null (which starts this chain reaction of nulls). Why would that be when I clearly have initialized it as shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array isn't initialised (well, it is, but it is initialised with nothings as the labels are nothing as the form instance is created).

Try filling it before parsing (in Form Load or in UpdateActuatorStatus):

```
     ActLabelLookup =
{{MTA91, MTA92, MTA93, MTA94, MTA95, MTA96, MTA97, MTA98, MTA99, MTA100},
{MTA81, MTA82, MTA83, MTA84, MTA85, MTA86, MTA87, MTA88, MTA89, MTA90},
{MTA71, MTA72, MTA73, MTA74, MTA75, MTA76, MTA77, MTA78, MTA79, MTA80},
{MTA61, MTA62, MTA63, MTA64, MTA65, MTA66, MTA67, MTA68, MTA69, MTA70},
{MTA51, MTA52, MTA53, MTA54, MTA55, MTA56, MTA57, MTA58, MTA59, MTA60},
{MTA41, MTA42, MTA43, MTA44, MTA45, MTA46, MTA47, MTA48, MTA49, MTA50},
{MTA31, MTA32, MTA33, MTA34, MTA35, MTA36, MTA37, MTA38, MTA39, MTA40},
{MTA21, MTA22, MTA23, MTA24, MTA25, MTA26, MTA27, MTA28, MTA29, MTA30},
{MTA11, MTA12, MTA13, MTA14, MTA15, MTA16, MTA17, MTA18, MTA19, MTA20},
{MTA1, MTA2, MTA3, MTA4, MTA5, MTA6, MTA7, MTA8, MTA9, MTA10}}
```

Comment: @Mort Ah, of course, the FormLoad is the event that triggers that label creation, and my initialization occurs before that. Thanks!

Comment: @nobby `Form_Load` _might_ trigger your label creation, but it's far more likely this is happening in the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Change the member-level declaration of ActLabelLookup to just:

```
Dim ActLabelLookup(,) As Label
```

In the form's **Load** event handler add a line to initialize it:

```
ActLabelLookup(,) =
{{MTA91, MTA92, MTA93, MTA94, MTA95, MTA96, MTA97, MTA98, MTA99, MTA100},
{MTA81, MTA82, MTA83, MTA84, MTA85, MTA86, MTA87, MTA88, MTA89, MTA90},
{MTA71, MTA72, MTA73, MTA74, MTA75, MTA76, MTA77, MTA78, MTA79, MTA80},
{MTA61, MTA62, MTA63, MTA64, MTA65, MTA66, MTA67, MTA68, MTA69, MTA70},
{MTA51, MTA52, MTA53, MTA54, MTA55, MTA56, MTA57, MTA58, MTA59, MTA60},
{MTA41, MTA42, MTA43, MTA44, MTA45, MTA46, MTA47, MTA48, MTA49, MTA50},
{MTA31, MTA32, MTA33, MTA34, MTA35, MTA36, MTA37, MTA38, MTA39, MTA40},
{MTA21, MTA22, MTA23, MTA24, MTA25, MTA26, MTA27, MTA28, MTA29, MTA30},
{MTA11, MTA12, MTA13, MTA14, MTA15, MTA16, MTA17, MTA18, MTA19, MTA20},
{MTA1, MTA2, MTA3, MTA4, MTA5, MTA6, MTA7, MTA8, MTA9, MTA10}}
```